# Python: Extract values from a dictionary embedded in another dictionary and list

Tags: python, dictionary

An API I'm using outputs the coordinates of a face from a picture as follows:

```
[{'faceId': '59b5b8ad-ea77-455b-bdef-6044883bab6a', 
'faceRectangle': {'left': 96, 'top': 51, 'width': 334, 'height': 334}}]
```

How can I extract the values from just the 'top' and 'left' keys (in this order)? I am looking for a simple output like this:

```
51
96
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that your list is named `mydict`

```
mydict = [{'faceId': '59b5b8ad-ea77-455b-bdef-6044883bab6a', 
'faceRectangle': {'left': 96, 'top': 51, 'width': 334, 'height': 334}}]
```

now `mydict[0]['faceRectangle']` will return:

```
{'left': 96, 'top': 51, 'width': 334, 'height': 334}
```

So what you need is

```
mydict[0]['faceRectangle']['left']
mydict[0]['faceRectangle']['top']
```